# What is the significance of .y and .y-next in the Raspberry Pi kernel branch names?

Tags: kernel

The [Raspberry Pi kernel repository](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux) has branch names that end in .y and .y-next? For example, `rpi-3.17.y` and `rpi-3.13.y-next`. What is the significant of the `.y` and `.y-next`?

Comment: You are more likely to get a response if you post the question in the raspberrypi.org/forums.  The chap who looks after the kernel, dom, is more likely to respond.

Comment: If you do get and answer please come back and answer it here for future searches.

Comment: Will do. For reference, I've asked the question on the RPi forums here: http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/search.php?author_id=83189&sr=posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.y` is just a placeholder.  The third number indicates a patch level with regard to security and important bug fixes.  The idea with these is that they are only done out of necessity -- they do not introduce new features, etc.  If you pay attention, you'll notice that the actual number, corresponding to one from the [vanilla source tree](https://www.kernel.org/), changes as the branch is updated.  You can get this from the commit comment on `Makefile` if you look down the top level list on the [git repo page](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-3.17.y) (currently, for that link to the 3.17.y branch, it's 3.17.4).

The `-next` branches appear to be the first (or at least, earlier) merges of a new minor number.  E.g. for 3.13.y-next the third number is actually 7, but for 3.13.y it is 11 (i.e., the -next one is an earlier version).  Since the rpi kernel is worked on a bit independently from the upstream source, I imagine these are left around in case those changes, made on the updated (non -next) branch, introduce a problem for someone somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense the y is a placeholder for the patch level. I'm going to wait a couple days before accepting this answer to see if anyone responds on the RPi forums.